# How to insert into another table after Registration on Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-relations

So, I have a laravel web and have some tables, two of them are `users` and `user_data`.
`user_data` have a foreign key `user_id` that references to `id` on `users`.

`users` have general attributes like username, email, password, etc. and `user_data` have 1 on 1 relation with `users` and have attributes like game_money, game_job, game_tier, etc.
The columns are too long if I combine those 2 into 1 table, so I tought to normalize it.

User registration is working and running smooth. But I don't know how to add a new entry into `user_data` when a new user registered and add a new entry in `users`. 
The attributes columns in `user_data` (like game_money,etc.) are filled by external application outside laravel, so all I need is to add an entry to `user_data.user_id` foreign key, and let the other attributes in user_data use the default values or null before being updated by the external apps.

Here is my `user_data` migration:

```
Schema::create('user_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->string('account_tier')->default("Free");
            $table->float('economy')->default(0);
            $table->string('job')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Where should I put the insert query inside laravel? Or should I handle `user_data` using the external app?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should make relationship between 2 table in Model first. After that, you can get, insert or even update 2 table easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an *id* on **user_data** table as your primary key. By the way you can just use the following code for your desired result.
In the registration method use something like below:

```
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

The user variable is holding the information of the newly created user. Now its time to insert into your user_data table. Assuming the model is UserData.

```
UserData::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
             ............
        ]);
```

Comment: I tried the code you given, after create the User model, when I create UserData, how to get the `id` of the newly created User? `$user->id` seems doesn't work. thank you

Comment: Do you have id on your user table? If so, $user->id should work perfectly.

Comment: Uh, it was working after i tried it again haha, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In RegisterController
inside create function

```
$user= User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
//UserData is the Model of user_data table
$user->UserData->create(['job'=>$data['job']]);
return $user
```

Comment: What should i add inside the UserData model? Is it just need a `protected $table = 'user_data'` ? I don't want to add anything like fillable because I don't insert those value via the webpage. Thank You

Comment: php artisna make:model UserData
inside it  add...
protected $table = 'user_data'
then
protected $fillable=['account_tier','economy','user_id','job'];
and make realtion with User and also in User model make the relation class with UserData

Answer (score 0):

Try To This Example:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    $user_data= array(
     'name' => $data['name'],
     'email' => $data['email'],
     'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    );
    $role_data= array(
     'user_name' => $data['name'],
     'email' => $data['email']
    );
    $response = DB::table('users')->insert($user_data);
    $response = DB::table('role')->insert($role_data);
```

Comment: Is it added inside RegisterController create method?, and what should I return? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Model boot events as following when you define relationship each other these models;

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::created(function($model){
        $model->userData()->create([
            'user_id' => $model->id,
            'job' => $model->job
        ]);
    });

}
```